# Auth guard not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to make auth guard work, but the variable `isLoggedIn` always remains `false`. I have tried adding as a core module but it is still returns `false`. I tried different approaches, but none is working.

```js
import { Injectable, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public getIsLoggedIn(): boolean {
        console.log("getIsLoggedIn() = " + this.isLoggedIn); // always false
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {

                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = response.json();
                if (user) {
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    return JSON.stringify(user);
                }
                return JSON.stringify({ user: "not found" });
            });
    }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.checkLogin();
    }
    checkLogin(): boolean {
        if (this.authService.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Initially I thought it was related to scope of the Variable. But  it is not. Did you find any solution? Pleas share with us.

Answer (score 1):

At the Login

```
localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
```

At your Guard

```
canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', //Rest of routes that requieres to be logged
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' }
```

];

Comment: Thankyou for response yeah it would work but i really wanted to know why it doenst update the variable there must be something

Comment: But if you store the season in a service, when you reaload the page you'' need to log in again, is that what you really want?

Comment: yes i do want that but i want to understand why it doenst update the variable

Comment: Question when you are debugging your "if (user) {" is it always undefined?

Comment: I am doing this.isLoggedIn = true; but on authguard but i doesnt get updated value .It is getting default value .which is false

Comment: Does the "user" object after the .json() is ok? becasuse when I do it like that doesn't work well... So let user = response.json(); does it actually set the json there or it does something else?, Are you providing your AuthService?

Comment: Yes it  is working well everything works well just loggedin is not updated

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you need to save your variable in a sessionStorage, like this:

```
public getIsLoggedIn(): boolean {
   var isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
    console.log("getIsLoggedIn() = " + this.isLoggedIn); // always false
    return this.isLoggedIn;
}
```

and set it this way:

```
  login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {

                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = response.json();
                if (user) {
                    //this.isLoggedIn = true;
          sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn')='true';
                    return JSON.stringify(user);
                }
                return JSON.stringify({ user: "not found" });
            });
    }
```

you should be good to go! that's what I use in my prod code.

However, if you still want to use your variable to hold such a value, you should take a look at Subjects. [This tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) explains it nicely.

Comment: Thankyou for response yeah it would work but i really wanted to know why it doenst update the variable there must be something

Comment: If you still want to achieve it through a variable, please take a look at Subjects in Angular 2/4. (e.g. private isLoggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();)